# Cant obtain userid when i redirect my uri to another page

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have my main page that asks for users to login, once they login everything works fine...i want to have the redirect_uri go to www.domain.com/file.php instead but when I try to accomplish this it does not send the user ID or any of the information with and the page **www.domain.com/file.php** displays User id: 0, compared to when there is no redirect there is some **User Id: 2132312312**.. here is my code

**header.php**

```
<?php 
require 'php-sdk/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'code',
    'secret' => 'code'
    ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
if ($user): //check for existing user id
    echo '<p>User ID: ', $user, '</p>';

    //print logout link
    echo '<p><a href="logout.php">logout</a></p>';
else: //user doesn't exist
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'=>'email',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://domain.com/file.php'
    ));
    echo '<p><a id ="fb_connect" href="', $loginUrl, '"><img alt="Connect Using Facebook" src="images/fb_connect.png"></a></p>';
endif; //check for user id  
?>
```

**file.php**

```
<?php 

 echo '<p>User ID: ', $user ,'</p>';
 if ($user) {
echo '<a id="logout" href="logout.php" >Logout</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use session variables to store user id.
& then fetch them on whichever page you want

Comment: I am pretty new to this..are you referring to the $_SESSION[] or the php sdk for facebook getSession()

Comment: i m referring to $_SESSION[]